# How to compare numeric in PostgreSQL JSONB

Tags: database, postgresql

I ran into strange situation working with `jsonb` type.

**Expected behavior**

---

Using short `jsonb` structure:

```
{"price": 99.99}
```

I wrote query like this:

```
 SELECT * FROM table t WHERE t.data->price > 90.90
```

And it fail with error `operator does not exist: jsonb > numeric` the same as text (`->>`) `operator does not exist: text > numeric`

Then I wrote comparison as mentioned in many resources:

```
SELECT * FROM table t WHERE (t.data->>price)::NUMERIC > 90.90
```

And it's works as expected.

**What's strange:**

---

```
SELECT * FROM table t WHERE t.data->price > '90.90';
```

a little weird but query above works right.

**EXPLAIN:** `Filter: ((data -> 'price'::text) > '90.90'::jsonb)`

But if I change `jsonb` value to `text`  as: `{"price": "99.99"}`
there is no result any more - empty.

**Question**: How actually PostgreSQL compare numeric data and what preferable way to do this kind of comparison.

Comment: `->` returns a `JSON` value, not a number

Answer (score 16, accepted):

But you aren't comparing numeric data, are you.

I can see that you think `price` contains a number, but it doesn't. It contains a JSON value. That *might* be a number, or it might be text, or an array, or an object, or an object containing arrays of objects containing...

You might say "but the key is called 'price' of course it is a number" but that's no use to PostgreSQL, particularly if I come along and sneakily insert an object containing arrays of objects containing...<sup>1</sup>

So - if you want a number to compare to you need convert it to a number `(t.data->>price)::NUMERIC` or convert your target value to JSON and let PostgreSQL do a JSON-based comparison (which *might* do what you want, it might not - I don't know what the exact rules are for JSON).

---

<sup>1</sup> And that's exactly the sort of thing I would do, even though it is Christmas. I'm a bad person.

Comment: No doubt operator `->` return `jsonb` value and `->>` return `text`. The question was way `jsonb` and `text` are comparable and other types not, for example ( `jsonb` and `numeric` throw error). But any way, I got you idea, Thanks.

Comment: If you ever want to check the type of something there is a handy system function `pg_typeof(<expression>)`

Comment: Thanks for the answer I've been searching everywhere.

Comment: Dito - very helpful and thanks a lot for that!